# jQuery offset().left vs offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

Currently I'm trying to speedup my code with refactoring from **jQuery** to **pure JS**.

I know that there are some other threads about this, but I couldn't find any which is equals to my problem.

Now I'm at the point where I want to get the same value with `offsetLeft` instead using `offset().left`

Does anyone know a simple explanation how to calculate the right value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) function to get this information:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('h1').getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

```html
<div>
  A
</div>
<h1 id="h1">Test</h1>
```

> However keep in mind that jquery is pretty optimized, and the code there is probably using exactly the same function, or probably something pretty close.

Comment: wow, thank you, it works. But what is the difference to offsetLeft?

Comment: It's exactly the same.

Comment: well no, offsetLeft returns another value than getBoundingClientRect().left

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you ask. Your question is about `offset().left` - what do you mean by `offsetLeft`? Where did it come from?

Comment: no, JS has offsetLeft too - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetleft.asp

Comment: So `offsetLeft` is pure JS, it's not related to jquery at all... you don't need to optimize that :)

Comment: Note that offsetLeft is related to the parent element (which is not always the viewport)